# training data SEQUENCE vs. training data SET?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My question is related to calssification in DataMining. But I believe anyone who has good background in Math/statistics can answer it.

As you remember a discrete-value training data of one dimension(e.g. sampling and quantizing a time signal) can be the

**sequence** [2,3,2,2] 
but a **set** should have unique values so the training **set** should be of the form
{2,3}.

I have the following table as my data **set** (the famous play golf example). this table stems from several realizations of a stochastic process:

```
 outlook         Temp.   Humidity      Windy   Play Golf
```

---

```
Rainy           Hot         High        False    No
Rainy           Hot         Low         True     No
Overcast        Hot         High        False    yes
Sunny          cold         High        False    Yes
?                ?          ?             ?      ?
```

As we see each feature(attribute) is a discrete variable. outlook can have 3 values. Temp.,Humidity and Windy can just have 2 values. As i said this table comes from several realizations.
so i know that by doing  many other experiments (realizations) all missing rows of this table can be completed (all combinations: 3*2*2*2=24).

This table is a *representation* of a Model(function or mapping) from these 4 features to ONE classes (Play Golf class).

Guys, Are you with me up to this point?

---

Here comes the question:

The (truth) above table is a way of representing a function(model) but it doesn't indicate how many times a realization can happen(its frequency).

for instance if i repeat the experiment 2 other times (2 realizations)
 and in both two cases i get for

outlook=Rainy, Temp=Hot, Humidity=High, Windy=False 
Play Golf=No ,

then i've obtained the same result as first row of my table.
but I can't add it to this table, because this table shows the **SETS** not the **repeated** values.

In my real database creation, i have training data values (from different realizations) that are repetitive, so they won't complete my table  because in a set we don't have a repeated value.So how can these repeated values help me in finding a Function(Model) for play golf?

thanks for your attentions and contributions